# How can I tell the difference between click events and swipe events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui2

I am using OnsenUI 2 with ReactJS for developing a Cross-Platform App with Cordova. It should run on mobile devices, but it would be nice if it works on normal browsers too. I have a Carousel Element with full screen images and when the user taps on the image I want to open a new page. The problem is, that every swipe to a new image is triggering a `click` event on the image. How can I tell the difference between a tap on the slide and a swipe to the new slide?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/amJooZ

Comment: Can you clarify if you are developing something for touchscreen devices or for computers?

Comment: Mainly for mobile / touchscreen devices, but it would be nice if it would also work on normal computers. The problem does not appear on a mobile device.

Comment: I added an updated answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing something for a touch screen, instead of listening for `click` events, you should listen for touch events. See [MDN's documentation of touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events). If it's important to handle normal click events as well, see [the section about handling clicks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Handling_clicks).